# pcm data support in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio, web-audio-api

For playing audio PCM data in HTML5 there in WebAudio API ( Chrome..) ,( mozSetup ,mozWriteAudio  in firefox ) .In these API Either We can append PCM data ( firefox ) and or give timer for play data ( noteon function in chrome ) . I search these type of API for internet Explorer but not able to find  out any way . Is there any way in IE for playing pcm data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing as powerful as the Web Audio API (or Audio Data API, which won't se further development since it's been rejected by the W3C) in Internet Explorer at the moment. The best you can do is to use the < audio > element, but it will only get you so far.. As far as I know, it won't let you write dynamic PCM data, without reverting to Flash etc.